# ALT Attribute Problem

Tags: magento-1.8

If anyone can help in regards the **`alt attribute`**, on

1. Where it is entered in **Magento**
2. How it can be entered?

Comment: From what alt attribute are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Since, at the time of answering you have not mentioned in which context, you are asking for the alt attribute, I assume that you are talking about the **product images**.

For the product images, by default, Magento uses the **product name** as the **alt** attribute value.

If you want to change it, you can set your custom value under the **Label** field for the individual image of the product.

[image: Alt Attribute value]

I hope it should solve your problem.

Please let me know if you want something else.